# Tensorflow aggregates scalar-tensor multiplication gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I multiply a vector with a scalar, e.g.:

```
a = tf.Variable(3.)
b = tf.Variable([1., 0., 1.])

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   c = a*b

grad = tape.gradient(c, a)
```

The resulting gradient I get is a scalar,

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>
```

whereas we would expect the vector:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 0., 1.], dtype=float32)>
```

Looking at other examples, it appears that tensorflow sums the expected vector, also for scalar-matrix multiplication and so on.
Why does tensorflow do this? This can probably be avoided using `@custum_gradient`, is there another less cumbersome way to get the correct gradient?

There are appear to be some related questions but these all seem to consider a the gradient of a loss function that aggregates over a training-batch. No loss function or aggregation is used here, so I think the issue is something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting scaler value because you took the gradient wrt scaler. You would get a vector if you took grad wrt some vector. Take a look to the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

a = tf.Variable(3.,  trainable=True)
b = tf.Variable([1., 0, 1.],  trainable=True)
c = tf.Variable(2., trainable=True)
d = tf.Variable([2., 1, 2.],  trainable=True)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
   e = a*b*c*d # abcd , abcd , abcd
   tf.print(e)

grad = tape.gradient(e, [a, b, c, d])
grad[0].numpy(), grad[1].numpy(), grad[2].numpy(), grad[3].numpy()
```

```
[12 0 12]
(8.0,
 array([12.,  6., 12.], dtype=float32),
 12.0,
 array([6., 0., 6.], dtype=float32))
```

Answer (score -2):

Formally, what I was looking for was the differential of the vector-field that is function of the variable `a`. For a vector-field the differential is the same as the Jacobian. It turns out that what I was looking for can be done by `tape.jacobian`.